# Appium + Watir + Chromedriver An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command

Tags: ruby, mobile, cucumber, appium, watir

I have on my project the following code:

features/env.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rspec'
require 'watir'
require 'webdrivers'
require 'yaml'
require 'fileutils'
require './features/Util/Tools.rb'
require 'json'
require 'watir-scroll'
require "mini_magick"
require 'watir-screenshot-stitch'
require 'appium_lib'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

    server_url = 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub/'

    capabilities =
    {
    platformName: 'Android',
    platformVersion: '7.0',
    deviceName: 'Android Emulator',
    browserName: 'Chrome'
    }

    $navegador = "chrome_dev_mobile"

    $appium_driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :desired_capabilities => capabilities, :url => server_url)

    $driver Watir::Browser.new $appium_driver
```

when I run my cucumber feature I get this error:

```
And Verificar Portal abierto                   # features/step_definitions/Home/Home_Chile/SD1_Home.rb:16
  An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: unknown error: Argument to isShown must be of type Element
    (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591059 (a3d9684d10d61aa0c45f6723b327283be1ebaad8),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
  UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: unknown error: Argument to isShown must be of type Element
    (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591059 (a3d9684d10d61aa0c45f6723b327283be1ebaad8),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
      at errorFromMJSONWPStatusCode (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:789:10)
      at ProxyRequestError.getActualError (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:683:14)
      at asyncHandler$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:400:25)
      at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
      at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
      at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
      at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
      at <anonymous>
  ./features/pages/Home/Home_Page/P1_HomePage.rb:20:in `verificar_pagina'
  ./features/step_definitions/Home/Home_Chile/SD1_Home.rb:17:in `"Verificar Portal abierto"'
  features/features/Pruebas_Mobile/CL_Mobile.feature:4:in `And Verificar Portal abierto'
```

That is the code inside  ./features/pages/Home/Home_Page/P1_HomePage.rb:20

```
def verificar_pagina
      @caja_busqueda.wait_until_present
      if @caja_busqueda.present?
        puts "Portal abierto satisfactoriamente con: " + $navegador
      end
  end
```

The mobile chrome open my URL and then appears this error. Please I try everythings, I accept suggestions

i set the appium chromedriver path manually and use it well. 
Seeing the appium log shows the following with more details:

```
[JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"d8b3f057fdc1e6e20a0007f9ed920514","status":13,"value":{"message":"unknown error: Argument to isShown must be of type Element\n  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600229 (3fae4d0cda5334b4f533bede5a4787f7b832d052),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)"}}
[W3C] Encountered internal error running command: ProxyRequestError: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: The request to /wd/hub/session/3345408e-82f9-4f63-b6ec-f82998806f47/execute has failed
[W3C]     at JWProxy.proxy$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/jsonwp-proxy/proxy.js:182:13)
[W3C]     at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
[W3C]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
[W3C]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
[W3C]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
[W3C]     at 
[MJSONWP] Matched JSONWP error code 13 to UnknownError
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/3345408e-82f9-4f63-b6ec-f82998806f47/execute/sync 500 110 ms - 1894
[HTTP]
```

Comment: Can you set Selenium::Webdriver.logger.level = :debug and provide the output? isShown is the name of the JavaScript atom that the driver executes to determine if an element is displayed on a page. For some reason the code is providing the driver an invalid element. Also, what version is your selenium-webdriver gem?

Comment: @titusfortner where can I refer about this isShown?

Comment: @rajagopalan Here is the relevant code: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/e09e28f016c9f53196cf68d6f71991c5af4a35d4/javascript/atoms/dom.js#L437

Comment: @titusfortner okay thanks.

Comment: I edited my question adding more details

Comment: My selenium-webdriver is selenium-webdriver (3.14.1, 3.14.0)

Comment: I need to see what object is getting sent as the value for the element from the selenium ruby bindings to the appium server. Please add a line setting the logs to debug as outlined in my first comment and post a gist or similar with the output.

Comment: Did you check my updated answer below? I still think it could be driver related. How do you start the Appium server?

Answer (score 0):

> (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100) & (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591059

On [this chromedriver page](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) they say you should use driver 2.43 for Chrome 69-71v.
Does updating the webdriver fix your issue?
v2.42 should also still support version 69 though. But there are a bunch of fixes mentioned, like this one:

> Fixed Not waiting until element is visible

Also I noticed the same isShown problem when I started appium via the desktop application. But what solved it for me was manually downloading the chromedriver and starting appium via the command prompt like described on [this Appium page](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver/).

`appium --chromedriver-executable /path/to/my/chromedriver`

Comment: I added more info to this answer. Can you check if you still have the issue when you tell appium to start with a certain chromedriver?

Answer (score 0):

I prove on this way:

```
require 'watir'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

    server_url = 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub/'

    capabilities =
    {
    platformName: 'Android',
    platformVersion: '7.0',
    deviceName: 'Android Emulator',
    browserName: 'chrome'
    }


    $driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :desired_capabilities => capabilities, :url => server_url)

    $driver.get "http://www.google.com"
```

It works!!!

But when a put

```
$appium_driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :desired_capabilities => capabilities, :url => server_url)
$driver = Watir::Browser.new $appium_driver
```

Then show the error when I try to interact with the locators.

Maybe the are a conflict between watir and selenium and appium, I dont know. 
It's a shame because I have an whole project on Watir made to web page and I can't reuse all of these code on mobile devices test.

Any suggest will be accepted